# How can I change the predefined Drools Flow process programmatically?

Tags: java, drools

a simpliest situation: I have a drools flow.
Very simple,like

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<process xmlns="http://drools.org/drools-5.0/process"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xs:schemaLocation="http://drools.org/drools-5.0/process drools-processes-5.0.xsd"
         type="RuleFlow" name="ruleflow" id="com.sample.ruleflow" package-name="com.sample" >

  <header>
  </header>

  <nodes>
    <start id="1" name="Start" x="16" y="16" width="48" height="48" />
    <actionNode id="2" name="Hello" x="96" y="16" width="80" height="48" >
      <action type="expression" dialect="mvel" >System.out.println("Hello World");</action>
    </actionNode>
    <end id="3" name="End" x="208" y="16" width="48" height="48" />
  </nodes>

  <connections>
    <connection from="1" to="2" />
    <connection from="2" to="3" />
  </connections>

</process>"
```

How can I change it programmatically , not with loading the flow file to XML Parsers etc, but to add the nodes and connection through the code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any Drools API will be there for modifying the rules

Comment: its not true, below is a very complex example of flow upgrade, but I need something much more simple, that will help just to add a new nodes

Comment: // migrate process instance to new version

Map<String, Long> mapping = new HashMap<String, Long>();

// top level node 2 is mapped to a new node with id 3

mapping.put("2", 3L); 

// node 2, which is part of composite node 5, is mapped to a new node with id 4

mapping.put("5.2", 4L); 

WorkflowProcessInstanceUpgrader.upgradeProcessInstance(

   ksession, processInstance.getId(),

   "com.sample.process2", mapping);